# Laravel 5 Get field of relationship modal

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have the following tables:

User

```
id
name
slug
city_id
```

City

```
id
name
```

User Modal

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\City');
}
```

City Modal

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
}
```

i want to be able to find by slug along with the name of the city in the same line. Is there a way of doing this without having to build a query? (name field conflict?)

the query i am using right now

```
    $this->user
        ->join('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'users.city_id')
        ->select('users.*', 'cities.name as city_name')
        ->where('users.slug', '=', $slug)
        ->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$user = User::find($userid);
```

or

```
$users = User::where('slug', $slug)->get(); //for many users
$user = User::where('slug', $slug)->first(); //for first user
```

then just use

```
$user->city->name;
$user->slug;
```

to get city variables. If many users, use foreach